# Change dynamical created fields with jquery

Tags: jquery

I need some basic help, on working with jQuery, as it is still new to me, and I can't get my head around it yet.

I have a dynamical created checkbox and input field, that I would like to manipulate through jQuery.

They are:

```
<input name="e19[i<?php echo $taeller-1;?>]" id="e19[i<?php echo $taeller-1;?>]" type="checkbox" class="check_kredit" <?php echo $checked = $foo['e19'] == '1' ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "";?>  value="1" onclick="postmtjek(this, '<?php echo $pl;?>', '<?php echo $res['ordre'];?>', '<?php echo $res['rev'];?>', '<?php echo $foo['e28']; ?>', '<?php echo $taeller-1;?>');document.getElementsByName('e20[]')[<?php echo $taeller-1;?>].value = this.checked ? '<?php echo date('d-m-Y');?>' : '';setOBdato(document.getElementsByName('e20[]')[<?php echo $taeller-1;?>]);" data-pris="<?php echo $foo['eStaalpris'];?>" data-datofelt="e20[]"/>
<input type="text" readonly class="listform" style="width:60px;" id="e20[]" name="e20[]" value="<?php echo sqltoalmdatetom($foo['e20']); ?>">
```

Basicly is gives the checkbox the names e19[i0], e19[i1], e19[i2], e19[i3] and so on. The input should be named like e20[][0], e20[][1], e20[][2], e20[][3] and so on.

When the checkbox is pressed I need to check, if the case is to expensive compared to with the costumer is insured for. If it's to expensive both the checkbox and input should be cleared, if not the checkbox should be checked and the input should show todays date.

My problem is, that I can't seem to get the right naming in place in jQuery, so that I can change the 2 fields.

My jQuery is like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var kreHint = $("#kreHint");
 var tekst_kredit_over_max = "Den samlede kreditbelastning inkl. denne sag overstiger kundens maksimale kreditbeløb. Det samlede beløb lyder på ";
 var tekst_kredit_under_max = "Aktuel kreditvurdering ";

 $(".check_kredit").click(function() {       //Class selector
    var chkbox = $(this).attr('name'); //<--- This returns the correct name of the checkbox
     console.log(chkbox);

 var salgspris = $(this).data("pris"); //Henter data-pris (DOM) property, i dette tilfælde indeholdende etapens pris
     $.get("/getkredit.php?k=<?=$res['kunde_id']?>", function(response){
         if (!(response == null)) {
             var kreditbelastning = parseInt(response.kreditbelastning);
             var kreditmax = parseInt(response.kreditmax);
             var samlet_kreditbelastning = kreditbelastning + salgspris;
                 console.log("Kreditbelast: "+kreditbelastning);
                 console.log("Salgspris :"+salgspris);
                 console.log("Kreditmax :"+kreditmax);
                 console.log("Samlet kreditbelast :"+samlet_kreditbelastning);

             if (kreditmax > samlet_kreditbelastning) {
                 kreHint.html(tekst_kredit_under_max + samlet_kreditbelastning); //Skriver tekst
             } else {
                 kreHint.html(tekst_kredit_over_max + samlet_kreditbelastning); //Skriver tekst

                 console.log("#"+chkbox);
                 $("#e19[i1]").prop('checked', false); //<--- this should be dynamical, not even this hardcorded name/id works???

                 $("#kreHint, #r599b").css({
                     "color" : "red",
                     "font-size" : "16px",
                     "font-weight" : "bold"
                 });
             }
        }
     });
 });
```

});

What am I doing wrong, and what should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery `attribute` selector like below:

```
$("[name='" + chkbox + "']").prop('checked', false);
```

[Learn more about jQuery Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Using `id` selector with `[` or `]`, You need to add `\\` before it.

```
//$("#e19\\[i1\\]").prop('checked', false);
$("#" + chkbox.replace("[", "\\[").replace("]", "\\]")).prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Okay, that worked, but why? I also tried this: var chkboxobj = $(this); var tmpnavn = "#"+chkboxobj.attr('id');
                     console.log(tmpnavn);
                     $(tmpnavn).prop('checked', false); but that didn't work either.

Comment: Because when you use `#` it will find element with `id` equal to that value. But your element doesn't have `id` as `e19[i0]` but it is `name` attribute.

Comment: I have both name and id on it, and it's the same: name="e19[i<?php echo $taeller-1;?>]" id="e19[i<?php echo $taeller-1;?>]". IF I change [name to [id it still works?????

Comment: and how do I put a value into the input box?

Comment: about the input I changed it's id to this: <input type="text" readonly class="listform" style="width:60px;" id="e20[<?php echo $taeller-1;?>]" name="e20[]" value="<?php echo sqltoalmdatetom($foo['e20']); ?>">. Then I'm able to catch it and manipulate it

Comment: For input `$("[id='" + chkbox.replace("e19[i","e20[") + "']").val(new Date())`

Comment: Found out that I could do the same as for the textbox, just like the checkbox : $("[id='" + datefield + "']").val(''); if I need it to be empty. But I still don't get, why I can't do this $("#e19[i1]").prop('checked', false); for the checkbox, when I have id on it.

Comment: As you can see in my answer `attribute` selector uses `[]` for selecting values. So jquery will consider `[` or `]` as a part of `selector` not as part of `id`. If you want to use it in `id selector` then you can prepend `\\ ` to it like `$("#e19\\[i1\\]").prop('checked', false); ` then it will work.